# SIP server for sip dialer

Tags: sip, voip, sip-server

I am a mobile app developer.
I want a SIP dialer with my own server , i have a VOIPROUTE from (VOIPROUTES.COM).
I want to use the sip for calling to pakistan, India and Bangladesh .
i want a dialer like Platinum Dialer( you can find it on itunes,google play,etc) 
for that i have to use a soft switch like (itel switch ).
How can i do all these things my own .
How can i make a server for sip through which my is connected to make a call .

And i hvae a question weather the app call directly to the sip ( voiproutes.com server ?) server or first it goes to my server where i do billing for that user .??

Which is best suited thing for me to do ??

Thnaks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common way to approach what you're trying to do is to use an application server that supports JSR 289 SIP Servlets. There are several on the market. A simple one that you can download for free for Java development purposes is the WebSphere Liberty server which can be downloaded from here: http://www.wasdev.net (SIP Servlet support is currently in beta). Note that Liberty can currently be used in production for small, single server deployments. Asterix is also a popular server for this. If you're looking for a cloud based trunking for PSTN federation from SIP check out Twilio's SIP trunking capabilities.